# How to take screenshot in UIAutomator with spoon?

Tags: android-uiautomator, spoon

I have used spoon open source tool for taking android device screen shot in robotium with the below code

```
Spoon.screenshot(solo.getCurrentActivity(), "Login_failed");
```

I want to take the screen shot using spoon in android UIAutomator tool .

Please let me know What should I pass instead "solo.getCurrentActivity()" in UIAutomator tool in Spoon.screenshot command .

I think if I get the getCurrentActivity in UIAutomator then I can pass argument , but I don't know how to get that ?

Comment: Can you please update me if you have solution for my issue ?

Comment: You can check how to get the current activity here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61060436/5555438. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply take the screen shots with below peace of code

```
 public void takeScreenShot() {
            Process process;
            try {
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        "screencap -p " + "/sdcard/imagename.png");
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

or else if we are using android target 18 and above we can us the built in method.

getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/imagename.png"));

Comment: Thanks Rajesh , can't we use spoon open source in UIAutomatior , please confirm !

Comment: We can use the external jars in the uiautomator by modifying the ant build xml uibuild.xml file which is located in sdk/tools/ants folder.